# Power of little o - asymptotic - series

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Consider the following, when $n \to + \infty$:

$$\log\left(1 + \frac{-1}{q}n^{\frac{1-q}{q}} +o(n^{-1}) \right)= R_1(n^{\frac{-1}{q}}) + o(n^{-1}).$$

And I am trying to determine the polynomial $R_1$. From a lemma, I know that this polynomial satisfies $R_1(0)=0$ and is of degree at most $q$, where $q$ is an integer $\geq 3$.

My problem is with the little-o notations, I don't see how to work with them.
I used the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ and have the following expression for the left-hand side :

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j+1} \frac{1}{j} \left(\frac{-1}{q} n^{\frac{1-q}{q}} + o(n^{-1})\right)^j $$

Can anybody help ? Thanks a lot inadvance !

Comment: I think that in your statement there's missing where the functions are $o(n^{-1})$; generally, when I say that a function $f$ belongs to the set $o(g)$ when $x \rightarrow x_0$ y mean that the quotient $\frac{f}{g}$ is defined on a neighborhood of the point $x_0$ and that it tends to zero as $x$ tends to $x_0$. As a matter of notation, when performing calculations we prefer not to think on $o(g)$ as a set of functions, but as a single function. We make this so we can write equalities like $o(g) + o(g) = o(g)$.

Comment: Some calculus books that use and explain this concept are the Zorich (*Mathematical Analysis*, vol. I), and the *Advanced Calculus* from Loomis.

Comment: You are right ! I forgot to mention I want the asymptotics when $n \longrightarrow \infty$. And thak you for the references! I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the logarithm using $\log(1+w)=w+\mathcal{O}(w^2)$, you find
\begin{align*}
& - \frac{1}{q}\frac{1}{{n^{1 - 1/q} }} + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(1)\left( { - \frac{1}{q}\frac{1}{{n^{1 - 1/q} }} + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right)^2 
\\ &
 =  - \frac{1}{q}\frac{1}{{n^{1 - 1/q} }} + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(1)\left( {\frac{1}{{q^2 }}\frac{1}{{n^{2 - 2/q} }} + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{2 - 1/q} }}} \right) + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)
\\ &
 =  - \frac{1}{q}\frac{1}{{n^{1 - 1/q} }} + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) + \mathcal{O}(1)o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right) =  - \frac{1}{q}\frac{1}{{n^{1 - 1/q} }} + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
\end{align*}
since, as $q\geq 3$,
$$
\frac{1}{{n^{2 - 2/q} }} \le \frac{1}{{n^{2 - 2/3} }} = \frac{1}{{n^{1 + 1/3} }} = o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{{n^{2 - 1/q} }} \le \frac{1}{{n^{2 - 1/3} }} = \frac{1}{{n^{1 + 2/3} }} = o\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$